# Referencing mutliple ID's within a JQuery call

Tags: jquery

New to Jquery and I think most of my troubles are from assumptions based on the many other languages I use.  The question right now involves the absolute traversal of an HTML id.  For example, given multiple sets of HTML with differing id's:

```
<div id="navi1">
    <div class = "linker">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="gfx/link1ver.png" /></a>
        <div class="expand"></div>
        <img src="gfx/divide1.png" />
    </div>
    <div id = "content1">
        test
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var a = ['#navi0', '#navi1', '#navi2'];
    var b = ['#content0', '#content1', '#content2'];

    $(a[0] + ' .expand').css({'background-color': '#017693', 'height': '50px'});
    $(a[1] + ' .expand').css({'background-color': '#01D092', 'height': '50px'});
    $(a[2] + ' .expand').css({'background-color': '#D0013F', 'height': '50px'});

    for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        $(a[i] + ' a').click(function() {

            for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++) { 
                if($(a[j] + ' .expand').css('height') == '300px') {
                    $(a[j] + ' .expand').animate( {
                        height: '0px'
                    }, 500);
                    $(b[j]).animate( {
                        width: '100px'
                    }, 500);

                }
            }

            $(this).next().animate( {
                height: '300px'
            }, 500);    

            $(b[i]).animate( {
                width: '500px'
               }, 500);     

        });     
    }


</script>
```

This is all just to test how Jquery works.  Regarding the question, the last animate attempts to perform on an id that isn't within the current 'this' or parent of 'this' at all.  How can I get there with this setup and is my use of array 'b' appropriate?  Would it be better to use a general class rather than unique content id's?

I've always been particular about good code, so by all means throw in tips however you like.

Comment: Can you please explain what the code is actually supposed to do? I can guarantee it can be done without nested (or any) for loops, but I've been looking at the code and just can't understand it (and I can't be bothered going through the for loop in my head). Also try setting up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) - might help us :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help folks.  Yesterday I made quite a messy, but functional version of what I am trying to do.  Hopefully this is an appropriate alternative until I can get it working in jsFiddle: http://dd630.nfshost.com/customer/techkid/test.html (keep in mind this mainly has to do with that last animate calling an external id)

Comment: I can't see a problem with your example, seems to do what it's supposed to do in Chrome at least.  

You should note you have a broken closing div in the code.  Look for </container>, I think you meant to close the #container div there, this might cause problems in other browsers.

Comment: @Simon The link I gave most definitely works, my post here was just a reworking of that tinkering draft.  I always figure these things out on my own, but with your help and the help of others here I knew I could make it more 'elegant'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to run the same code over and over again with for loops, you can use classes and let jQuery automatically apply the same code to multiple objects with the same class.

First, change the HTML to this:

```
<div id="navi1" class="nav">
    <div class = "linker">
        <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="gfx/link1ver.png" /></a>
        <div class="expand"></div>
        <img src="gfx/divide1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

The changes are to add a class to the top level nav div and to put a class on the link and on the content.

Then, you can use this code to respond to the click:

```
$(".nav .toggle").click(function() {
    var this$ = $(this);
    var parent$ = this$.closest(".nav");
    // get all .expand elements that are not in the one we clicked on
    $(".nav").not(parent$).find(".expand").each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.css("height") == "300px") {
            self.animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
            self.closest(".nav").find(".content").animate({width: "100px"}, 500);
        }
    });
    // set the state of the one clicked on
    this$.next().animate({height: "300px"}, 500);
    parent$.find(".content").animate({width: "500px"}, 500);
});
```

You'll notice that there are no for loops at all.  It just uses either use jQuery's `.each()` or uses the fact that jQuery will operate on all items that match the selector without manually iterating.

There are two sections to this code.  The first section operates on the `.nav` items that are not the one that was clicked on (to reset their state) and the second section operates on the `.nav` item that is the one that was clicked on.  It doesn't use any IDs at all, but rather goes to the parent .nav and the finds the relevant items by class name in the block it's working on.

If you control the full HTML page, I'd recommend using CSS to set the initial background color and height rather than javascript:

```
.nav {height: 50px;}
#nav1 {background-color: #017693;}
#nav2 {background-color: #01D092;}
#nav3 {background-color: #D0013F;}
```

If you had to do it with javascript, you could use this to avoid repeated code and make it table driven:

```
var naviSettings = [
    {sel: '#navi0', bColor: '#017693'},
    {sel: '#navi1', bColor: '#01D092'},
    {sel: '#navi2', bColor: '#D0013F'}
];

for (var i = 0; i < naviSettings.length; i++) {
    var item = naviSettings[i];
    $(item.sel + " .expand").css({"background-color": item.bColor, height: "50px"})
}
```

Comment: This is the exact logic I was attempting to implement.  In my case, ID's aren't needed at all, so using just a .navi class may force me to javascript the details.  Humor me: my call for an id deep in a click function, I was under the impression that I would have to lead it out of the tree to find it since it was an id and not a class.  This assumption was incorrect?

Comment: @cantide5ga - sorry, I don't understand your question.  I used classes so that you can have identical structure and code for each block and the code can work identically within a given block.  Since an ID can only appear once in a page, you can't use the same IDs in different blocks.

Comment: It's okay, I don't either.  My question: can a single click function perform on various other id's within the page without traversing operations?  Can I simply ask for it as-is since it could easily be identified in the DOM tree?

Comment: @cantide5ga - yes. Any time you want to reference an element by id you can just say `$("#theId")` - or, without jQuery, `document.getElementById("theId")`. The whole point of id is to let you reference the element directly rather than traversing to it from some other part of the DOM.

Comment: @cantide5ga - a single click function can will operate on all the objects that are contained in the jQuery selector as in the code in my answer.  If you want code within the `click()` function to operate only on items in the clicked block, then you will have to either use traversal functions like I did in my answer or you will have to use a specific id that is unique to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I've made a jsFiddle and modified your code. You'll see you don't need to use for loops at all to bind the handlers. I gave every div it's own ID, so you set the border and background colour using CSS (after all, this is what CSS is for).

See: http://jsfiddle.net/GpEqA/1/

The code goes like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.link').click(function() {
        $(".link").not(this).each(function() {
            $(this).find("div.wrap").hide();
            $(this).find("div.expand").animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 300);

            $(this).find("div.services").animate({
                width: "0px"
            }, 300);
        });

        $(this).find("div.expand").animate({
            height: "300px"
        }, 500);

        $(this).find("div.services").animate({
            width: "647px"
        }, 500, "", function() {
            $(this).find("div.wrap").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join:

```
$(b.join(','))
```

See an example here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/bZJAf/